# Automatic numbering of points during digitization in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, digitizing

Does somebody know how to automatically number the points during digitization in Qgis. To explain, when I create the new point there is the window where I must to type the point number. Is there any way to automatic number without manually typing of point number?

Comment: Do you mean ID number?

Comment: QGIS has option to not open that window - Settings / Options - Digitizing tab - Feature creation - Suppress attribute form pop-up. After digitization is finished, you can  use $rownum or $id to fill all at once. Will that do?

Comment: @Miro: this is probably the best solution (the way I usually do that actually). No need that the ID is generated at the same time features are created.

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution if I want all number to be between 1 and N, but I want some numbers to be from 1 to N and many of them to be some other sign, for example 1-16-4A. Because that I can`t use this method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is to use a **virtual field** which would automatically number your points using the `$id` expression (or whatever expression you prefer):

[image: Field Calculator]

---

Note that you will need to save a project file for this as virtual fields are saved in the **.qgs file** and not in the shapefile itself (but you can re-save the shapefile as a new one using the `Save As...` option which would convert the virtual field into a normal one).

Answer (score 4):

I think you talk about the id of shapefiles, if so you can go to layer properties (doubleclick the layer) then go to fields and set the item that is called 'Bearbeitungselement' in german to UUID-Generator (id field type must be text) as shown in the screenshot below (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

[image]

When digitizing your points (or other geoemtries as well, of course) you get this:

[image]

and you will just have to enter the other attribute values if applicable.